# Subscribe to MQTT topic in SwiftUI iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, mqtt

I'm writing a small iOS app to send MQTT messages to a broker which is hosted on a Raspberry Pi companion computer on my quadcopter.  In the iOS app primary view, the app will connect to MQTT Broker (check), send messages associated with several buttons (check), and monitor various quadcopter telemetries such as mode, distance, and lat/long.  The iPhone app will display the drones position and the user's position (check) on a map.

The part I'm having issues with currently is having the app maintain a continuous subscription to a topic and then update several variables in the code.  Currently, the code below contains the subscription line and "did receive message" code inside of of a button view which only works momentarily when that button is pressed.

I've tried pasting this code in various places within the content view with no success; admittedly I'm a novice coder and Swift/iOS is very new to me.  Ideally, the app would continually monitor certain topics and update several variables to equal the message when certain topics are posted to by the drone.

---

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI
import CocoaMQTT


struct Drone {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var distance: UInt8
    var direction: UInt8
}

//
struct ContentView: View {
    @State public var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.0000, longitude: -86.0000), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.001, longitudeDelta: 0.001))
    
    @State private var trackingMode = MapUserTrackingMode.follow
    
    @State private var safety = false
    
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    
    @State public var Connection:Bool = false
    
    var Bee: Drone = Drone(coordinate: .init(latitude: 34.0010, longitude: -86.0010), distance: 10, direction: 180)
    
    
    let mqttClient = CocoaMQTT(clientID: "swift", host: "mqtt.eclipse.org", port: 1883)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack {
            HStack{
                Text("Beer Bee")
                
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.mqttClient.username="user"
                    self.mqttClient.password="password"
                    self.mqttClient.keepAlive=60
                    self.mqttClient.connect()
                    self.Connection.toggle()
                    
                    }, label: {
                        Text(Connection ? "Disconnect":"Connect")
                    })
            }

            
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .zoom, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: $trackingMode)
            HStack {
                Text("Flight Mode")
                Spacer()
                Text("Distance")
                Spacer()
                Text("Position Accuracy")
            }
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Toggle(isOn: $safety) {
                    //action here
                }
                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color.red))

                Button("Main") {
                    self.mqttClient.publish("topic/dronetest", withString: "hello world!")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            
            Button("Hold") {
                self.mqttClient.subscribe("topic/dronetest")
                self.mqttClient.didReceiveMessage = { mqtt, message, id in
                    print("Message received in topic \(message.topic) with payload \(message.string!)")
                }
            }
             Spacer()
            Button("Manual Control") {
                self.showingSheet.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                SecondView()//region: self.region, Connection: self.Connection)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=View@*/Color.yellow/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my first answer in StackOverflow and I'm a novice too. I was having the same problem, but I can solve it by declaring the "didConnectAck" for the mqttClient; the subscription remains. Just add the following missing lines to your code:

```
self.mqttClient.didConnectAck = { mqtt, ack in
   self.mqttClient.subscribe("topic/dronetest")
   self.mqttClient.didReceiveMessage = { mqtt, message, id in
      print("Message received in topic \(message.topic) with payload \(message.string!)")
   }
}
```

Also, (maybe?) can be useful to add the following line in your first button:

```
self.mqttClient.autoReconnect = true
```

I hope I can help you with this answer. Good luck.